# Does vs2015 and 2013 upgrade the .net framework of that machine to a specific version, or have prerequisites?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5

My build server has .net 4.5.1 installed on it (out of support, I know).

If I install visual studio 2015 on it, will it upgrade the framework to a newer version? If so what version? Or, does it have a .net framework prerequisite?

I don't think that 2013 predates 4.5.1, but same question - does vs2013 upgrade to a specific .net version, or have a framework version prerequisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.6.2 is included in vs2015.
.NET Framework 4.5.1 is included in vs2013.

Seems like if they are not installed, Visual Studio will install them along with it.

[Source](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html)